# Create index based on message field - appname

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

****Logstash.conf code *******

input {

```
    stdin{
        type => "stdin-type"
    }

file{
    type => "json"
    path => [ "C:/prod/*.log", "C:/prod/*/**.log"]
    start_position => "beginning"
    tags => "prod"
    }

file{
    type => "json"
    path => [ "C:/dev/*.log", "C:/dev/*/**.log"]
    start_position => "beginning"
    tags => "dev"
    }
```

}

filter {

```
     grok {
    match => {
    "message" => [ "%{JSON:payload_raw} "]
    }
        pattern_definitions => {
        "JSON" => "{.*$"}
```

}

```
json {
    source => "payload_raw"
    target => "payload"
    }


mutate {
    remove_field => [ "payload_raw","message" ]
        }


date {
    match => [ "[payload][datetime]", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
    target => "@timestamp"
    }
```

}

output {

```
    stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
    }
    elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{tags}-logs"
    }
```

}

---

Sample log

{datetime":"2021-08-10 04:11:37,825","servername":"VM-0001","serverip":"(null)","process":"2404","thread":"4","level":"DEBUG","appname":"Dev-Email","page":"Program.cs"}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample document your shared, your `elasticsearch` output needs to look like this:

```
elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{appname}-logs"
}
```

Also know that index names are **not allowed** to contain uppercase letters, so `Dev-Email` will need to be lowercased (using the [`mutate/lowercase` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-lowercase)) before being used as the index name.

Comment: My requirement is create index name of appname field  value(Dev-Email). It should create multiple index appname field  value(Dev-Email).

Comment: Can you update your question with the full exact error you got from the ES logs?

Comment: Actually earlier i can not fully explain to you about my Question.

Comment: My requirement is create index name of appname field value(Dev-Email). It should create multiple index appname field value(Dev-Email). if appname value changed then index should be create with changed value

Comment: My above comment still stands, I'd like to understand why you're getting those errors and what they are.

Comment: Sorry for previous comment. it was not error. now my requirement is :----  My requirement is create index name of appname field value(Dev-Email). It should create multiple index appname field value(Dev-Email). if appname value changed then index should be create with changed value

Comment: Yes, and my answer provides the solution you're looking for. What happens when you implement it?

Comment: After implementing this, there is an index on the name of  %{appname}-logs, but when I go to create the index and search by name of %{appname}-logs, it says that the name is not match and its own value which is (Devi mai) search by name then it showing same.

Comment: This means that the document doesn't have any field called `appname`. Can you double check the sample document you've shared?

Comment: if you see sample log which i shared with you. Yes appname field is there with value (Dev-Email).

Comment: It doesn't make sense because, for instance, that document doesn't have the `@timestamp` field which is set by your `date` filter. Or is everything in the `payload` structure inside your document?